# JavaFX- Freeze some columns in a table

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to freeze some columns (or rows) in a JavaFX table, such that if one scrolls right (or down), say 2 columns (or 2 rows) stays stationary and other columns are scrolled as usual?
Using two tables will bring in a lot of complexity, like syncing the scrolls etc. Want to avoid this option.